# Renaming and moving files with specific file extension

Tags: python, function, file, class, operating-system

This is my code to perform file operations such a move, rename, delete bulk files with specific file extensions

```
import os


class OperationsOnFiles:
    def __init__(self, src_path):
        self.src_path = src_path

    # Prints the name of all the files with the extensions in the folder specified
    def src_files(self):
        print("All the files in the source folder are: ")
        print()
        i = 1
        for file in os.listdir(self.src_path):
            print(str(i) + ". " + file)
            i += 1
        return ""

    # Renames all the files or files with specific extension in the folder with a number attached to the end of the file name
    def rename_bulk_files(self):
        i = 0
        file_path = self.src_path
        for file in os.listdir(file_path):
            dot_index = file.index('.')
            if not files_extension or file_path.endswith(files_extension):
                file_src = os.path.join(file_path, file)
                file_des = os.path.join(file_path, file[0:dot_index] + "_" + str(i) + file[dot_index:])
                os.rename(file_src, file_des)
                i += 1

        print("All files have been renamed")

    # Move files or files with specific extension in one folder to another folder
    def move_bulk_files(self):
        file_path = self.src_path
        destination_folder_path = input("Enter the destination folder in which you want to move the files: ")
        for file in os.listdir(file_path):
            if not files_extension or file_path.endswith(files_extension):
                src_path = os.path.join(file_path, file)
                des_path = os.path.join(destination_folder_path, file)
                os.replace(src_path, des_path)
        print("All files have been moved to the destination folder")

    # Delete files or files with specific extensions in a folder
    def delete_bulk_files(self):
        path = self.src_path
        for i in os.listdir(self.src_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(path, i)
            if not files_extension or file_path.endswith(files_extension):
                os.remove(file_path)
        print("All files have been deleted")


source_folder_path = input("Enter the source of the folder on which you wish to perform the operation: ")
my_operations = OperationsOnFiles(source_folder_path)
print("File Operations: \n1. Rename Bulk Files \n2. Move Bulk Files \n3. Delete Bulk Files")
user_choice = int(input("Enter a number to perform the operations: "))
files_extension = input("Enter file extension of the file to be deleted or press 'ENTER' to delete all files: ").lower()
if user_choice == 1:
    my_operations.rename_bulk_files()
elif user_choice == 2:
    my_operations.move_bulk_files()
elif user_choice == 3:
    my_operations.delete_bulk_files()
else:
    print("Please enter a valid input")
```

In the function rename_bulk_files and move_bulk_files, when I type a specific extension, the function block is not working but it is working for the delete_bulk_files function. I have used the same logic for the former functions as the later function but it is not working.

And I want to pass *files_extensions in rename_bulk_files and move_bulk_files so that you can specify multiple file extensions separated by a comma. So if you enter .pdf, .mp4, .docx, all the files with these extensions will either be renamed or moved. But I can't seem to do that too.

Comment: Try passing files_extension variable to functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misshandled your file_paths in between your functions.

In the delete function you define the individual file path based on the directory path.

```
def delete_bulk_files(self):
    path = self.src_path
    for i in os.listdir(self.src_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(path, i)
        if not files_extension or file_path.endswith(files_extension):
            os.remove(file_path)
    print("All files have been deleted")
```

You forgot to do that in the other functions

```
def move_bulk_files(self):
    file_path = self.src_path
    destination_folder_path = input("Enter the destination folder in which you want to move the files: ")
    for file in os.listdir(file_path):
        if not files_extension or file_path.endswith(files_extension):
            src_path = os.path.join(file_path, file)
            des_path = os.path.join(destination_folder_path, file)
            os.replace(src_path, des_path)
    print("All files have been moved to the destination folder")
```

Thus, the code will not execute (unless the input is empty and files_extension is False).

So just add the extra line to adjust the path in the other functions aswell

```
file_path = os.path.join(path, i)
```

It should work as intended afterwards.

**Some more things apart from your question**

You should improve the variable naming within you code. For instance, if you define a self.path variable in your **init** func based on the user input, theres no need to declare a variable path=self.path in sub functions of your class, just replace it with self.path directly, this will increase the readability for your code.

Also, as far as i know os.replace cannot handle movement between different disks. Therefore you should think about switching that responsibility to the shutil.move() function.

And in general, you should think about packing the use prompts into your class aswell. The critical drawback of your program at that point is that the entire thing is shut down after one operation and needs to be started again. Like that you can look way ahead in terms of functionality!

**EDIT**
The code below works as intended on my system. I have commented the respective lines with an '!'. Although I really hope that you figured it out yourself by now. It's a very simple syntax mistake tbh.

```
import os


class OperationsOnFiles:
    def __init__(self, src_path):
        self.src_path = src_path

    # Prints the name of all the files with the extensions in the folder specified
    def src_files(self):
        print("All the files in the source folder are: ")
        print()
        i = 1
        for file in os.listdir(self.src_path):
            print(str(i) + ". " + file)
            i += 1
        return ""

    # Renames all the files or files with specific extension in the folder with a number attached to the end of the file name
    def rename_bulk_files(self):
        i = 0
        path = self.src_path
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            dot_index = file.index('.')
            #file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
            if not files_extension or file.endswith(files_extension):  # !
                file_src = os.path.join(path, file)  # !
                file_des = os.path.join(path, file[0:dot_index] + "_" + str(i) + file[dot_index:])
                os.rename(file_src, file_des)
                i += 1

        print("All files have been renamed")

    # Move files or files with specific extension in one folder to another folder
    def move_bulk_files(self):
        path = self.src_path
        destination_folder_path = input("Enter the destination folder in which you want to move the files: ")
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            #file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
            if not files_extension or file.endswith(files_extension):  # !
                src_path = os.path.join(path, file)  # !
                des_path = os.path.join(destination_folder_path, file)
                os.replace(src_path, des_path)
        print("All files have been moved to the destination folder")

    # Delete files or files with specific extensions in a folder
    def delete_bulk_files(self):
        path = self.src_path
        for i in os.listdir(self.src_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(path, i)
            if not files_extension or file_path.endswith(files_extension):
                os.remove(file_path)
        print("All files have been deleted")


source_folder_path = input("Enter the source of the folder on which you wish to perform the operation: ")
my_operations = OperationsOnFiles(source_folder_path)
print("File Operations: \n1. Rename Bulk Files \n2. Move Bulk Files \n3. Delete Bulk Files")
user_choice = int(input("Enter a number to perform the operations: "))
files_extension = input("Enter file extension of the file to be deleted or press 'ENTER' to delete all files: ").lower()
if user_choice == 1:
    my_operations.rename_bulk_files()
elif user_choice == 2:
    my_operations.move_bulk_files()
elif user_choice == 3:
    my_operations.delete_bulk_files()
else:
    print("Please enter a valid input")
```

Comment: I suppose you did not correct it fully. If you add the line `file_path = os.path.join(path, i)` naturally you have to correct according to your variable names. I did not assume that i have to debug and rewrite your code on my own but to give you the hint to do it yourself. So you either add the line for the full path or you handle your file (instead of file_path) according to your for-loop directly.

Comment: Thanks, dude! Now I realize the mistake I made. I didn't debug the code properly otherwise I would have corrected it.